# SQL Server -- Elegant way to use custom fields for record set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for an elegant way to select fields from a view, where a second supporting table defines the fields that should be selected.

The view contains all of my employee data.  The constraint table contains the field name, which references the view field name, and a bit which signifies to select that field.

Example of View:

```
Name   | Age | Weight
Peter  | 38  | 180
Martha | 25  | 115
```

Example of constraint table:

```
Field  | Enabled
Name   | 1
Age    | 0
Weight | 1
```

...Where after running the query, the following data should return:

```
Name   | Weight
Peter  | 180
Martha | 115
```

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: try using a table valued function where you build a dynamic sql SELECT statement, you can then use it within another query, to join to, etc

Comment: Elegance is a very poor thing to go for when accessing and designing datbases.  Try for effectiveness and performance first, elegant is often the worst possible way to query a database.

Comment: I was handed off some very nasty TSQL, whereas I cannot change the artchitecture of the decision -- right now it's a bunch of cursors and barely understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
( field varchar(70),
[enabled] int)

DECLARE @SELECT VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SELECT = ''
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('Name',1)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('Age',0)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('Weight',1)

SELECT  @SELECT = @SELECT + field + ', '
FROM @TABLE
WHERE [enabled] = 1

SET   @SELECT = LEFT(@SELECT,LEN(@SELECT)-1)     --trim last ,

SET @SELECT = 'SELECT ' + @SELECT + ' FROM MyView'

PRINT @SELECT
--EXEC @SELECT
```

will execute

```
SELECT Name, Weight FROM MyView
```

Bring on the dynamic sql haters.

Using this like a table or view is not trivial but it is possible, first wrap it in a stored procedure, then create a linked server 'loopback'

```
if exists (select * from master..sysservers where srvname = 'loopback')
    exec sp_dropserver 'loopback'
go
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'loopback',
    @srvproduct = N'',
    @provider = N'SQLOLEDB', 
    @datasrc = @@servername
go
```

Then you can use the following syntax:

```
select * FROM openquery(loopback, 'exec yourSproc')
```

Comment: Wow -- that's awesome.  I'm a little lost how you didn't do that without a loop through the fields though?

Comment: And so now the client code gets different column names, datatypes and nullability... a.k.a. how does the client know that it won't get "age"? This dynamic SQL now breaks the client-db contract, surely

Comment: @gbn, your absolutely right, using this in a client app would be ill advised, although there are plenty of ways that it could still work, just depeneds on requirements.

Comment: plop on top! wrap that in a table valued function and you can use it like a view and join to it

Comment: @KM, not you can't do that, Table valued UDF return a fixed type only

Comment: I've added a method for querying it like a table or view.

Answer (score 5):

Without dynamic SQL you can't: SQL is a "fixed column contract" language

I'd suggest using the constraint data in the client to hide data and don't do this in the database